# Ruby / Rails - Advanced grouping with group_by

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called event_recurrences it contains 2 important columns `event_id` and `cached_schedule`

`cached_schedule` contains an array of dates

`event_id` is used to reference the event

I need to

1. Get all the event_recurrence objects `@something.event_recurrences` - Done
2. Go through each recurrence object and get the `event_id` and all the
   dates from `cached_schedule`
3. Iterate through each month, and spit out a list like the following

Jan

event_id date

event_id date

event_id date

Feb

event_id date

... and so on

To recap the `event_id` is located `event_recurrence.event_id` the dates that the `event_id` will happen on are located in an array inside `event_recurrence.cached_schedule`

Some I have some incomplete code to work with...

This code works successfully to show each `event_recurrence` object by month using the `created_at` field.

in my controller

```
@schedule_months = @something.event_recurrences.order("created_at DESC").group_by { |e| e.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

in my view

```
<% @schedule_months.keys.sort.each do |month| %>  
    <div class="month">
        <%= month.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    </div> 
  <% for event in @schedule_months[month] %>  
    <li><%= event %></li>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely, jBeas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some details missing from your question... for example, can the dates in `cached_schedule` span multiple months, or are they all guaranteed to be in the same month?

If you just want to use core Ruby:

```
dates = []
@something.event_recurrences.each do |er| 
  er.cached_schedule.each { |date| dates << [date, er.event_id] }
end
@event_dates = dates.group_by { |(date,event_id)| date.mon }
```

Then in the view:

```
<% @event_dates.keys.sort.each do |month| %>
  <div class="month"> <%= month.strftime("%B %Y") %></div>
   <% @event_dates[month].each do |(date,event_id)| %>
      <li><%= date %> <%= event_id %></li>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You may have to adjust the code a little depending on the specifics, but this should give you the idea. Note the use of destructuring assignment: `@event_dates[month].each do |(date,event_id)|`. This saves a line of code and expresses what the code is doing more clearly.

If you don't mind adding your own extensions to the core Ruby classes, you could make this code even cleaner and more consise. I often use a method which I call `mappend`:

```
module Enumerable
  def mappend
    result = []
    each { |a| enum = yield a; enum.each { |b| result << b } if enum }
    result
  end
end
```

The name is a mix of `map` and `append` -- it is like `map`, but it expects the return value of the mapping block to also be `Enumerable`, and it "appends" all the returned `Enumerable`s into a single `Array`. With this, you could write:

```
@event_dates = @something.event_recurrences.mappend { |er| er.cached_schedule.map { |date| [date, er.event_id] }}.group_by { |(date,event_id)| date.mon }
```

OK, that might be a lot for one line, but you get the idea: it saves you from using an intermediate variable to accumulate results.

**UPDATE:** Something like `mappend` is now part of the Ruby core library! It's called `flat_map`.

Comment: for example, can the dates in "cached_schedule" span multiple months, or are they all guaranteed to be in the same month? - They span multiple months. Thanks again! Going to try this now!

Comment: I designed the code so it should work even if the dates span multiple months (but not the same month in different years). I haven't tested it yet, so you may have to do a little debugging, but like I said, it should give you the idea

Comment: There are a few things to change but I got it working from your example. :) I will update the example when finished. Thank you so much for helping me with this.